# Is there a way to pass list as one of the arguments in argparse

Tags: python, argparse

I'm writing PySpark jobs for which I want to pass several arguments. One of them should have list of strings and also one list as well. I'm having trouble figuring out how to pass list to the list of argument.

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='My pyspark job arguments')

parser.add_argument('--job', type=str, required=True, dest='job_name', help='The name of the spark job you want to run')
parser.add_argument('--res-path', type=str, required=True, dest='res_path',help='Path to the jobs resurces')
parser.add_argument('-l', '--list', action='append', required=True, help='List of list')

args = parser.parse_args()
```

When I pass values in CLI:

```
--list currency
--list RSD EUR
```

I want output of --list to look like this:

`['currency', ['RSD', 'EUR']]`

Comment: Check out https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/7.x/, this library is super helpful when working with complex CLI structures

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`nargs` lets you do something close:

```
parser.add_argument('--list', action='append', nargs='+')
```

will produce `[['currency'], ['RSD', 'EUR']]`. One drawback is that no positional arguments can be used immediate after `--list`, as they will be consumed as arguments of `--list` itself.

Comment: End-of-options `--` can be used to delimit positional arguments

Comment: @VPfB True, but that also prevents any other options from being used. You can also just specify another (valid) option to stop `--list` from consuming more arguments (`--list a b c --foo ...`). It has to be valid, because otherwise `argparse` raises the expected "unrecognized argument --foo" error.

Comment: (So it's *a* way to allow positional arguments, but not the only way.)

Comment: For some reason, I cannot combine `append` with `nargs`. I'm getting this error `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'append'`